# Azure APIM - Terraform - Use same AAD group for multiple products errors out

Tags: azure, terraform, product, terraform-provider-azure, apim

Getting an error message when using the same Azure AD group for two different groups.
The error I get says the group is already in the TF state and can't be used again.
Hopefully someone has seen this error before.

```
        dev = {
            product1 = {
                product_name                    = "Product-1"
                approval_required               = true
                published                       = true
                subscriptions_limit             = "2"
                aad_group_obj_id                = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                aad_group_name                  = "AG-Azure-Sample-Group"
                product_policy                  = "../policy-samples/base-policy.xml"
            }
            product2 = {
                product_name                    = "Product-2"
                approval_required               = true
                published                       = true
                subscriptions_limit             = "2"
                aad_group_obj_id                = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                aad_group_name                  = "AG-Azure-Sample-Group"
                product_policy                  = "../policy-samples/base-policy.xml"
            }
        }
    # ========================================================================
    # Product for BU APIs
    resource "azurerm_api_management_product" "custom_product" {
      product_id            = var.product_name 
      api_management_name   = var.api_management_name
      resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
      display_name          = replace(var.product_name, "-", " ")
      # Require subscription keys for API access
      subscription_required = true
      approval_required     = var.approval_required
      published             = var.published
      subscriptions_limit   = var.subscriptions_limit
    }
    
    # Relate group to a product, for each is if we want to use developer or guest built in groups
    resource "azurerm_api_management_product_group" "assignments" {
      for_each            = toset([azurerm_api_management_group.external_group.name])
      product_id          = azurerm_api_management_product.custom_product.product_id
      group_name          = each.key
      api_management_name = var.api_management_name
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    }
    
    # Create default policy for Product
    resource "azurerm_api_management_product_policy" "apim-product-policy" {
      product_id          = azurerm_api_management_product.custom_product.product_id
      api_management_name = var.api_management_name
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      xml_content         = file(var.product_policy_file_path)
    }
```

Comment: Hi @mac, which TF resource do you use? Is it `azurerm_api_management_product`?

Comment: Hello, I'm indeed using azurerm_api_management_product, assigning it to aad groups and finally creating a default policy for it.                                                         
Please see the code above, just added it.

Comment: Seems like from the portal I have no trouble adding the same AAD group to a Product. Perhaps this is just related to Terraform.

Comment: ``` # Assign AAD groups to Product
resource "azurerm_api_management_group" "external_group" {
  name                = var.aad_group_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  api_management_name = var.api_management_name
  display_name = var.aad_group_name
  description = "This group is link to AAD group ${var.aad_group_name}"
  external_id = "aad://my tenant ID/groups/${var.aad_group_obj_id}"
  type        = "external"
}```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by separating the group creation from the assignment. Problem was that the module creating the group was executed every time the group was assigned to the product. Now I have a separate map which contains the groups to be added to the API and on the assignment module I pull in the group via a data block segment. Works like a charm.